# Stop executing code

Tags: vb.net

I am compiling and running code at runtime. Can I stop this code midway through if I wish? Like the 'stop' feature in Visual Studio that stops the code if desired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, if you attach the Visual Studio debugger to the running process.

- Load the solution that produced the application into Visual Studio
- Run your application outside of Visual Studio
- Choose **Debug** -> **Attach to process...** from the Visual Studio menu
- Select your application in the process list
- Click **Attach**

You should now be able to use the normal debugging controls to pause execution of your application, step through code, etc.

Comment: I am not sure if it is classified as a running process... I have some vb.net code in a textbox, and I compile and run this at run time. Would the Visual Studio debugger work in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called the task manager (find your process and kill it). Or if you're in a console window, just use Ctrl+C.